# java apache ftpServer file upload and download isn't working

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtual-machine, ftp-server

Im using Apache FtpServer and built my own ftp server. I`m using this server on a VM (VPS). Im able to login and list the files however, Im couldn't download or upload files. Every time I try I get the error

```
220 Service ready for new user.
USER testuser
331 User name okay, need password for testuser.
PASS ********
230 User logged in, proceed.
FEAT
211-Extensions supported
SIZE
MDTM
REST STREAM
LANG en;zh-tw;ja;is
MLST Size;Modify;Type;Perm
AUTH SSL
AUTH TLS
MODE Z
UTF8
TVFS
MD5
MMD5
MFMT
211 End
OPTS UTF8 ON
200 Command OPTS okay.
SYST
215 UNIX Type: Apache FtpServer
STAT /
212-
drwx------   3 user group            0 Oct 25 02:46 lost+found
drwx------   3 user group            0 Oct 25 06:27 v
-rw-------   1 user group         4496 Oct 25 06:30 working.txt
212 End of status.
TYPE I
200 Command TYPE okay.
PORT 10,9,226,222,220,45
200 Command PORT okay.
STOR /Records.xls
150 File status okay; about to open data connection.
220 Service ready for new user.
```

When I run the code on localhost, I can download, modify and upload files. Why this isn't working on a VM?

Comment: I finally got it to work using command line instead of any ftp clients